# How to understand Clifford+T from a quantum information theory perspective

Tags: information-theory, stabilizer-code, clifford-group, fault-tolerance, mutual-information

I'd like to study the important operator set Clifford+T from a quantum information theory perspective.

The Clifford+T set is universal and it is important because allows for efficient error correction protocols.

So, for example, what interesting observations there can be about this set in terms of: capacity bounds; entropies; mutual information; reference and/or environment system; (stabilizer) codes.

Comment: Questions should be on point; yours is way too vague. What exactly are you interested in? Clifford+T is universal, so you do *anything* with it to arbitrary accuracy ...

Comment: Yes you can simulate any *unitary* with arbitrary accuracy. But the Clifford+T set is important because it allows for error correcting codes. So my interest is in how to analyse such a set from a noise perspective, hence involving tools like the ones I listed.

Comment: That's not quite correct. In fact, by dilation, it is possible to approximate any quantum channel with that gate set. Albeit, there is still no concrete question; please be more specific! I don't know what you mean by "analysing such a set from a noise perspective". Usually, you have to analyse the code you're interested in! E.g. for noise thresholds, transversal gate sets, etc.